# How do i get this php debugger in laravel

Tags: laravel, debugging

i have download a laravel project from github, When i run the project i got an debugger menu.

I am very new to laravel.

How do i get this debugger menu in my other projects
[image]

Comment: It would help to know which project you downloaded.

Comment: https://github.com/mrakodol/Laravel-5-Bootstrap-3-Starter-Site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have shown is the debug bar from the [`barryvdh/laravel-debugbar`](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) package. This is the package you want to use if you have other Laravel projects.

If you have other non-Laravel projects, you want the [`maximebf/php-debugbar`](https://github.com/maximebf/php-debugbar) package. The `barryvdh/laravel-debugbar` is a nice Laravel wrapper around the base `maximebf/php-debugbar` package.

You can view the linked packages for installation instructions.

Answer (score 1):

Add `laravel-debugbar` in `composer.json`, like `"barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^2.0@dev",`

Add `Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider::class,`, `'Debugbar' => Barryvdh\Debugbar\Facade::class,` to `providers` and `aliases` in your `config\app.php`.

Please don't forget run: `composer update`